# How to change protocol to https on wagtail sitemaps?

Tags: python, django, seo, wagtail

I have a django sitemap and wagtail sitemap for my site.

The django sitemap is using https by simply setting the protocol variable in the class, but I can't figure out a way to do this for the wagtail sitemap without overriding many internal methods.

Is there a simple way to use https for my wagtail sitemaps?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the Wagtail admin, under Settings -> Sites, change the port number of your site to 443.

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew there had to be an easier way lol. Don't know how i missed that

Comment: Make sure to reload / redeploy your app to see the changes in sitemap.xml